# Getting data from a particular column from a table in hash set

Tags: java, jdbc, hashset

I am Retrieving some tables from database and storing those table names in a hashset.  Code I am using to retrieve table is as follows

```
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  hash. add(rs. getString(3) ) ;
}
```

Now I have tables in a hash set.

Now I want to retrieve data from all these tables in a hash set for  particular column 'student'. And put all values in a list. I want to retrieve all distinct values of column student in all these tables.  Table may contain or may not contain this student column.  If a table contains this column then  I want to store its distinct values in a list.  Please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can not extract table data using the databasemetadata. Databasemetadata will only provide you the details of table like name, columns, datatypes etc. You need to make the JDBC connection with the database and then need to fire the select query to get the desired result. 
Below is the simple JDBC program to do so:

```
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
// get tables from database
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  hash. add(rs. getString(3) ) ;
}
// getColumns of table 'tableName'
ResultSet rs2 = md.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
boolean found = false;
while (rs2.next()) {
String columnName = rs2.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
if (columnName.equalsIgnoreCase("student")) {
found = true;
break;
}
}
if (found) {
String driver = "provide the driver for database here like com.mysql.....";
String url = "provide the connection url here like jdbc://...."
String userName = "provide DB username"
String password = "provide DB username"
Class.forName(driver)
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password)
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
Resultset rs3 = null;

// Now take the tableName from your hashset and pass it into below query.
String query = "select student from " + tableName;
rs3 = st.executeQuery(query);
While(rs3.next()) {
// Store the results anywhere you want by obtaining 'rs3.getString(1)'
}
}
```

Hope this resolves your problem. Please ignore typos in code if any.

Comment: I am getting error if column student is not present in table.. How to handle it?

Comment: @zaib7777 Lets do this: Get the column names of a table(using offcourse databasemetadata) prior to making the connection and check if the  the column name matches with your intended name i.e. student. If yes then only go for extracting the data from table. Will it solve your problem?

Comment: Could you please show a sample code.. It will be helpful for me to understand your last comment

Comment: `DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs2 = md.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
boolean found = false;
while (rs2.next()) {
String columnName = rs2.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
if (columnName.equalsIgnoreCase("student")) {
found = true;
break;
}}
if (found) {
// code to fetch data goes here
}`

Comment: Should I replace it with my above code or to write this code after it.. Sorry for this silly question I am new to jdbc

Comment: @zaib7777 I've updated the code in main answer as per your need. Don't forget to accept the answer and upvote the comments.

Comment: Have you checked the case sensitivity of column or table name? Also may be the problem due to column name might need quotes..Post the table definition in question and which database u r using?

Comment: I m using sybase

Comment: U need to check the column name by enclosing it in square brackets[]. Rest all satisfies the answer. Please resolve this by accepting it.